# Cache-Control: no store Vs Cache-Control: no store, no cache

Tags: http, http-headers

Is the following enough to inform browsers that they are not to store response data after a session?:

```
Cache-Control: no-store 
Pragma: no-cache
```

Is the above the same as:

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache 
Pragma: no-cache
```

and if not what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
Cache-Control: no-store
```

`no-cache` is redundant. It means that a stored response shouldn't be served without revalidation, but since there *isn't* a stored response when using `no-store` it doesn't have any effect here.

And `Pragma` has [no meaning](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9111#section-5.4) as a response header.

I'm not sure what you mean by a "session". HTTP caching doesn't have that concept. Both `no-cache` and `no-store` will apply to the very next request, regardless of the browser context.